# play audio that are embedded in pdf file

Tags: sound, pdf, adobe

I have a PDF file that has audio embedded in it. In Windows the audio is played when I click the link after opening the pdf file in Adobe Reader.

I opened the same file in adobe in Ubuntu, however am unable to play them, after clicking on the audio link, a dialog box pops up saying you need a media player to play the file, after clicking the allow tab on the dialog box, it takes me to [this page](http://www.adobe.com/special/acrobat/nomediaplayer.html).

Please assist, how can I play those embedded audio file in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for embedded Multimedia within a PDF is new in Adobe Reader 8.1.1 for Unix platforms.  Unix Reader supports Real media, so you should be able to play embedded video if you have Realplayer installed. You cannot, however, play MPEG or QuickTime files as those players are not supported by Unix Reader.

Can you try it after installing real player? What is the version of Adobe Reader you are using? What is the format of the audio file?

Comment: I think either totem or mplayer should play RealPlayer media - so I dont think you need to install Real Player as well.

Comment: thanks a lot @janmejay, I'm using adobe 9, I installed Real Player, installed it from [here](http://forms.real.com/real/player/download.html?f=unix/RealPlayer11GOLD.deb) and now am able to play the embedded audio files.