# How to play embedded midi audio in PDF file?

Tags: pdf, midi

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and using Adobe Reader 9.

When I click on the embedded file link in the pdf file I get a dialogue box saying

> Multimedia Player Finder: The media requires an additional player.
>   Please click 'Get Media Player' to download the correct media player.
>   To play the media, you will need to close and restart the application
>   once the player is complete.

When I click on Get Media Player the dialogue box closes but nothing further happens.

I have looked at this question:

[play audio that are embedded in pdf file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53622/play-audio-that-are-embedded-in-pdf-file)

and downloaded RealPlayer but still continue to get the same problem.  I have also installed timidity without any result.

If it would help to use some other pdf reader that will allow me this functionality then I would be happy to do that as an alternative as well.

All help gratefully received.

Comment: Still looking for an answer? Do you by chance have a PDF with a midi file I could tinker with?

Comment: Thanks for the offer @Seth. I got round the problem by requesting the author to send me the midi files separately which he did.