# How to play audio embedded in pdf?

Tags: sound, pdf

I have already checked this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53622/play-audio-that-are-embedded-in-pdf-file) but today, neither realplayer nor acroread are available for linux. I do not want to use old deprecated applications that could introduce security holes as well.

I am currently creating pdf document slides using lualatex and the beamer class. But there's no point at testing anything if the sounds can't get played!

So, is there a pdf viewer that plays sounds that are embedded in a pdf file? Or, has anyone information about evince being able to play such sounds or not?

EDIT: here is an example of pdf file provided as example:
http://www2.le.ac.uk/departments/mathematics/extranet/staff-material/resource-downloads/beamer-presentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally installed okular, though I do not have kde, so it came with lots of dependencies along.

The sounds do work, but transduration times are not respected by okular. This behavior is a bug in version 20.2 of okular. It has been fixed in version 20.3.

For those having the 20.2 and who cannot install a newer version (like those who use Ubuntu 14.04), there's a kind of workaround: in okular settings, presentation tab, **check** the "Advance every:" option and set a value that is greater than any of the transdurations of the document, otherwise okular will advance sooner *even if this option remains unchecked*. (This is the bug).

Well, then you can then start the presentation.